# Construction of a MGF for conditional random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

This question is motivated by the comment under the answer in [understanding of difference between weighted variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629976/understanding-of-difference-between-weighted-variables/3631139#3631139).

Let $X_i, i=1, \ldots, n$  be independent Poisson random variable with parameters $\lambda_i$ correspondingly and conditioned such that $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=A$. Let $a_i, i=1, \ldots, n \in R$. Denote $S=\sum_{i=1}^N a_iX_i$

Find Moment generating function $M_S(t)$ for $S$.

I have been trying to go through the steps noted in the above cited answer, but, since there is an extra condition on the variables, I have not been able to succeed.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84098

Comment: @kimchilover - (1) the link you provided covers the case of equal $\lambda_i$.  For the case of different $\lambda_i$, is it still multinomial but with $\lambda_i / \sum_j \lambda_j$ as the probabilities for each option?  (2) even if it is, how to go from there to $M_S(t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As has been pointed out in the comments, $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ conditioned on $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = A$ is multinomial with $p_i = \lambda_i/\sum_j \lambda_j$, $i=1,\ldots,n$,  and number of trials $A$.
2. The MGF of a multinomial $(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ with parameters $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ and number of trials $n$ is
   $$
   E[e^{\sum_{i=1}^k \theta_iX_i}]  = \left(\sum_{i=1}^k p_ie^{\theta_i}\right)^n
   $$
   (Note that this is the multidimensional version of an MGF, which is why you have the linear combination.)
3. To get the MGF of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i$ conditioned on $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=A$, apply this result to get:
   $$
   E[e^{\theta \sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i}|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=A] = E[e^{\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta a_i)X_i}|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=A] = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_ie^{\theta a_i}\right)^A
   $$

You can see some calculations for Step 2 here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61697/moment-generating-function-of-multinomial-distribution (Note, $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i = 1$, so I think the calculations can be simplified.)

Comment: Thank yo for your answer. May I ask you to elaborate step 3), please, I cannot understand how the last equation is to the power $A$. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I see why this choice of letters is confusing. When you condition on $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = A$, you are creating a multinomial with $A$ trials. And in the MGF from step 2, the power you raise to is the number of trials.

Comment: (And I edited to correct $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i = 1$; previously it said $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i = n$.)